# Uso de un módulo ES desde HTML da ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html, chrome, modulos

Soy nuevo en los ESmodules. Trato de hacer una prueba simple de carga de uno para probar, pero me da error. Tengo un HTML que carga el módulo y el js del módulo:

**index.html**

```
<script type="module">
    import {App} from './modules/app.js';
</script>
...
<script>
    var app = new App();
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App{
    constructor(){
        console.log('App loaded');
    }
}
```

**Resultado:** *Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined at (index):55*

He probado varias alternativas:

- Poner un timeout de 5s antes de instanciar *App*, por si fuese problema de que no está cargado el módulo todavía.
- Cargar el módulo directamente en el *src* de la etiqueta *script*.
- Poner *default* a la clase en el módulo.

No estoy usando Babel ni bundler alguno (quiero ver cómo funciona antes de complicar las cosas). Es un Chrome actualizado a última versión.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La única forma que puedas usar la sintaxis de módulos es sirviendo los mismos desde un servidor y no leyendolos desde una carpeta local. ¿Estás sirviendo tu sitio desde un servidor web?

Comment: Efectivamente, ejecuto un servidor con node (usando http-server). De hecho, no da error de carga alguno, ni error de sintaxis. El módulo se carga y aparece cargado en la pestaña sources de las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Une el código, estás importando la librería en un módulo pero luego quieres usarla fuera del mismo:

```
<script type="module">
    import {App} from './modules/app.js';
    //Script definido con tipo "módulo", App debería existir
</script>

...
<script>
    //Script que no es un módulo y no tiene acceso al módulo anterior
    var app = new App();
</script>
```

Seguramente te funcionará si haces algo como

```
<script type="module">
    import {App} from './modules/app.js';
    const app = new App();
</script>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, funciona. Y esto me hace entender muchas cosas del funcionamiento.
¡Muchas gracias!